# jQuery on hover image change opacity/fadeout and text fade in

Tags: jquery, hover, opacity, fadein, fadeout

I am a complete novice when it comes to jQuery and I know there are a lot of questions on this site similar to mine but I couldn't find one close enough to what I wanted.

What I would like is when a mouse hovers over an image, for the image to reduce in opacity (or for it to fadeout completely) and for text to fade in over the top of where that image was. I would also like that text to be a link to a position on that same page (I'm sure I can manage that though).

If anyone could put something together in jsfiddle for me that would be very much appreciated as I am not capable enough yet of being able to modify jQuery existing examples to what I need.

Thanks!

Comment: Show us what you've done already.

Comment: Can't you just use the all "new" and "hot" CSS? Like with :hover, :active or CSS3 pseudos like :before and :after? Or is browser support of importance to you? Actually CSS :hover with opacity is widely supported (except IE, use filters here).

Comment: @MarkusHofmann `"..is widely supported ( except IE"` This is why we can't use any of the "new" or "hot" things :(

Comment: Can you use css with a js fallback? Actually opacity does work in elder IE (IE<9) if you use -ms-filter's in your css. BUT!! It might slow down the css parsing in some browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, may be it will help you:

HTML:

```
<img class="image" src="" alt="TestImage"></img><a id="link">This is the link content</a>
```

CSS:

```
 #link {
    display: none;
 }
```

Script:

```
$(".image").hover(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).fadeOut('slow', function(e) {
          $('#link').fadeIn('slow');
      });
});

 $("#link").mouseout(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).fadeOut('slow', function(e) {
          $(".image").fadeIn('slow');
      });
});

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".image")[0].hover(); 
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ebXCr/4/)

Updated Script:

```
$(".image").hover(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).stop().fadeOut('slow', function(e) {
          $('#link').stop().fadeIn('slow');
      });
});

$("#link, .image").mouseout(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if($(this).is("img"))
      {
          $(".image").stop().fadeOut('slow', function(e) {
              $('#link').stop().fadeOut('slow', function(e) {
                  $(".image").stop().fadeIn('slow');
              });
          });
      }
      else
      {
          $('#link').stop().fadeOut('slow', function(e) {
              $(".image").stop().fadeIn('slow');
          });
      }
});

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".image")[0].hover(); 
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WDmKR/)

Comment: This is just what I wanted. Thank you very much. One more thing I forgot to mention, was when the mouse moves off/away from the image, the text fades out and the image fades in again. What would the script be for that?

Comment: Updated the post, please check

Comment: Thanks Abhishek. With your script, you need to move the mouse over the text then move it away from it before the text fades out and image fades back in. Is it possible to have it that when the mouse moves off the faded image area, it is then the text fades out and image fades back in. Also this works well in jsfiddle, but I can't get it to work in Dreamweaver or Rapidweaver. Any idea why?

Comment: Hope you are having jQuery reference added.

Comment: Yes I am. How would I do the script in my post above re text fading out and image fading in without having to mouse over the text first?

Comment: No worries, with the script that you wrote above, when the text is visible, to make it fadeout, you need to move the mouse over it before it fades out. I was thinking that when you move the mouse away from the text (or faded out image) the texts fades out and image fades back in, avoiding having to move the mouse over the text before it all happens. Hope that's clearer :)